# AS3: Download a download embedded file to desktop without browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating an flash app where users can select something and download a temple. I'm publishing this file using air application with runtime embedded. In the app I've included a folder called documents with the individual files the user can download. Currently I'm using navigateToURL but I don't want it to rely on the browser. I've also tried this:

```
function surveyDownload(evt:MouseEvent):void {

var request = new URLRequest("document/template.docx");  
var localRef = new FileReference();    
    try  
    {  
        // Prompt and download file  
        localRef.download( request );  
    }  
    catch (error:Error)  
    {  
        trace("Unable to download file.");  
    } 
}
```

but all I get is the trace statement "Unable to download file".

How can I download an embedded file without the browser?

Comment: You are confusing things. Since this is an app and the files are included with it, the user doesn't have to download anything since the files are already on the computer. Maybe you mean move the files? Anyway File and FileStream class is what you need.

Comment: I wanted to set it so when the user click the button the templates will download to their desktop. I will give File and FileStream class a try. Thanks for your responds!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear. You want the user to download something from a *server*? If so then `document/template.docx` is not a URL so of course that will not work.

If you are talking about copying a file out of the AIR app bundle to the user's hard drive then you don't need `URLRequest` but rather the methods in the [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#methodSummary) class (`browseForSave` and `copyTo`).

Read the docs for `File` and search out some tutorials – there are loads and more complete than I would write here.

Comment: Yes I mean files that are bundles with the Air App. Sorry about the confusion. Its been a while since I've worked with Flash and I'm pretty new to AS3. Thank you for your help!